# Training SVM classifier using bigrams in python

Tags: python, svm, n-gram, text-analysis

I am trying to analyze tweets using SVM classifier. I was able to successfully perform the classification using unigrams as the features. I am using SciKit’s implementation of libSVM that can perform multi-class classification using One-Vs-All approach. In order to generate a feature vector, I made use of a map. If the word exist in the tweet, it was mapped to 1 else to 0. In the feature vector, the value of the map(word) was then appended with the label 0 if it was no cessation tweet else to 1. The code is here:

```
def getSVMFeatureVectorAndLabels(tweets, featureList):
sortedFeatures = sorted(featureList)
map = {}
feature_vector = []
labels = []
for t in tweets:
    label = 0
    map = {}
    # Initialize empty map
    for w in sortedFeatures:
        map[w] = 0

    tweet_words = t[0]
    tweet_opinion = t[1]
    # Fill the map
    for word in tweet_words:
        # process the word (remove repetitions and punctuations)
        word = replaceTwoOrMore(word) 
        word = word.strip('\'"?,.')
        # set map[word] to 1 if word exists
        if word in map:
            map[word] = 1
    # end for loop
    values = map.values()
    feature_vector.append(values)
    if(tweet_opinion == '0'):
        label = 0
    elif(tweet_opinion == '1'):
        label = 1
    labels.append(label)            
# return the list of feature_vector and labels
return {'feature_vector' : feature_vector, 'labels': labels}
# end
```

In this code, tweets contains a list of (unigram,label) and the featureList is a list of all the uniques words extracted from the tweets. 
On the same lines of this code, I wanted to know if I can use bigrams as a feature, how do I do it by generating best bigrams and creating a feature vector? For generating bigrams for naive bayes, I used this code:

```
#extract features using bigram
def extract_bigrams(tweet, score_fn=BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, n=10):
bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tweet)
bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(score_fn, n)
d = dict([(ngram, True) for ngram in itertools.chain(tweet, bigrams)])
d.update(best_word_feats(tweet))
return d

def best_word_feats(words):
return dict([(word, True) for word in words if word in bestwords])

best = sorted(word_scores.iteritems(), key=lambda (w, s): s, reverse=True) [:10000]
bestwords = set([w for w, s in best])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sklearn's `CountVectorizer` to do this for you. See [this guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html), in particular, the line of code

```
>>> bigram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2),
...                                     token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b', min_df=1)
```